# What is the main purpose of the google.inject.Injector plugin feature?

Tags: java, plugins

I'm studying the source code of a desktop-app called [Tomighty](https://github.com/ccidral/tomighty/commit/d3b84cd2d11cde5ca4bc90add2e45d2b94fc4004), and I keep seeing code that has this package at the top:

```
import com.google.inject.Injector;
```

then I see this code at the top:

```
@Inject private Injector injector;
```

May someone explain please what is the point of this code, and why is it needed here?

Comment: Did you do any research? See https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/

Comment: Did it answer your question? I am curious why you asked without checking google